# Can you have multiple groupings of axis labels in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I'm trying to build a column chart that has groups it's data by quarter, then by year...

```
| Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 |
|        2008       |        2009       |
```

I have been unable to find any examples of this in the flex docs. Is this possible to do in Flex 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're essentially stacking two axes on top of each other. Here is the respective link: [Multiple Axes](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_types_12.html)

Comment: This works well for numeric axes, but I'm trying to do this with category axes. Any additional thoughts?

Comment: Well, the two axes you showed in your example are numeric. It should still work for category axes I think... You may have to make a custom axes object if it comes to it.